# How could I detect of my smart device is touchable?

Tags: java, javascript, ios, html, windows-phone-8

I've a application where a person must use a controller by the use of the touchscreen of the smart device. So I have written some code to detect of the smart device has a touchscreen if not the application gives an error message.

the code is like this:

```
var canvas,
    c,
    container,
    // is this running in a touch capable environment?
    touchable = 'createTouch' in document,
    touches = []; // array of touch vectors
var firstboot = true;
lastFrameTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();

function init() {
    if (touchable) {
        setupCanvas();
        setInterval(draw, 1000 / 24);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd, false);
        window.onorientationchange = resizeCanvas;
        window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
    }
    else {
        setupCanvas();
        c.textAlign="center";
        c.fillStyle = '#000';
        c.font="18px Arial";
        c.fillText("Helaas, de controller is alleen beschikbaar voor toestellen met een touchscreen.",canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);   
    }
}
```

For smart devices with Android of IOS the code works fine and the touchscreen is detected. But when I try the controller on my windows 8 phone (Nokia lumia 920) I get the error message my phone has no touchscreen.

So how could I change my code so my application detect that my windows phone is touchable?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest try jquery plugin [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com)

if this works u might get some idea from there script.

Answer (score 0):

The Modernizr.touch test only indicates if the browser supports touch events, which does not necessarily reflect a touchscreen device. For example, Palm Pre / WebOS (touch) phones do not support touch events and thus fail this test. Additionally, Chrome (desktop) used to lie about its support on this, but that has since been rectified. Modernizr also tests for Multitouch Support via a media query, which is how Firefox 4 exposes that for Windows 7 tablets.

refer to this article 
[Touch event](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/)